# Vectorizing Generalised Hebb Algorithm

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

I have this code which runs very slow. Can someone help me vectorize it.

```
for ii=1:K,
    y=w*x(ii,:)'; % y is N by 1
    u=zeros(N,M);
    disp(num2str(ii));
    for jj=1:N,
        u(jj,:)=y(jj)*(x(ii,:)-y(1:jj)'*w(1:jj,:));
    end
    wold=w;
    w=wold+eta*u; % updated weight matrix
end
```

the inner loop takes the most time. The code is for generalised hebb algorithm.

**Input sizes:**

```
M=153600;
K=5000;
N=400;
eta=0.004;

size(w)=5000x153600
size(x)=400x153600
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *kill* the inner loop to get `u` with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
yN = y(1:N);
u = bsxfun(@times,yN,bsxfun(@minus,x(ii,:),cumsum(bsxfun(@times,w(1:N,:),yN))))
```

For the outer loop, owing to the data dependency between iterations with the updates on `w`, it might be hard to vectorize that one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This does reduce time considerably. Though still it appears to be a bit slow(274.285267 seconds for one iteration.). Do you think changing: `wold=w;w=wold+eta*u;`to `w=w+eta*u` will be somewhat helpful.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Yes! That should help a lot. You are saying it's slow at `274 secs`, so what was the runtime before vectorizing?

Comment: I didn't measure it before, but it would around 3x improvement if not more.  Any other improvements you suggest?I changed it to`w=w+eta*bsxfun(@times,w*x(ii,:)',x - cumsum(bsxfun(@times,w,w*x(ii,:)'),1));`. Readability doesn't matter to me here.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia `3x` improvement with the vectorization over original code or is it `3x` worse now? I would keep it at `w=w+eta*u`.

Comment: 3x  times faster than before.

Comment: Can you explain why `w=w+eta*u.` would be better?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia You can certainly experiment with it, but from my experience, you would be doing too many calculations in one-line, which isn't always guaranteed to give huge improvement.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia And if you are looking for `100x`, please switch language, go low-level. Or wait for my `BSXFUN Pro` version, pre-order starting soon ;)

Comment: Are you talking about writing code in `c` then calling it in `matlab`? What is `BSXFUN PRO` by the way, sounds interesting?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Mate that was a joke :) "writing code in c then calling it in matlab" would be mex, so that could be tried too.

Comment: Sorry I had made a slight error in the dimensions. K and N aren't equal. If possible can you modify the answer according to the new edit.

Comment: Will the update in the dimensions the code you posted shows error. But I am unable to make modifications, please check whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Do you think using a .mex file instead could result in some speed up?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia It might, I am not sure.